# objectFromJSONString in JSONKit.h returns null in iOS

Tags: ios, jsonkit

Please do the following to reproduce the problem

```
NSString *url = @"http://qdreams.com/laura/index.php?request=EventWeekListings&year=2012&month=10&day=22";

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@" , json);
NSDictionary *deserializedData = [json objectFromJSONString];
```

*deserializedData*  would contain *nil*. Expected behavior is to return proper dictionary.

Is that because total number of JSON dictionary elements exceed a certain threshold?

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the NSJSONSerialization method JSONObjectWithData:options:error: it worked fine for me.

```
    NSString *url = @"http://qdreams.com/laura/index.php?request=EventWeekListings&year=2012&month=10&day=22";
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

After Edit: I ran the code again this morning, and like you I got null. The problem with dataWithContentsOfURL. is that you have no control and no way to know what happened if something went wrong. So, I retested with the code below:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self loadData];
}

-(void) loadData {

    NSLog(@"loadData...");
    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qdreams.com/laura/index.php?request=EventWeekListings&year=2012&month=10&day=22"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 10.0];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse...");
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData...");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %ld bytes of data",[data length]);
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError...");
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",[error localizedDescription],[[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    //lblError.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed! Error - %@",[error localizedDescription]];
    self.receivedData = nil;
}


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading...");
    NSError *error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Finished...Download/Parsing successful");
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 
            NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }
}
```

There was an error, and the log of error.localizesDescription was: "The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted". So, it appears that there is something wrong with what's coming back from the server which prevents the JSON parser from working correctly. I also printed out the string along with the error message. Maybe you can look at it carefully and try to figure out what's wrong with the data.

Comment: Can you please run that again? Your code snippet did not work for me.

Comment: @user1208616 This line:                                     "EventUrl": ""www.geteyesmart.org/eyesmart/injuries/index.cfm"" is causing a parse error because of the double quotes before www (and at the end).

Answer (score 0):

looking at your json you start with the array value (using square brackets) without a name. try reformatting you response with something like this:

```
 {"results":[...the rest of your response..]}
```